# Cast an Int32 NAN in a float

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, swift

I need to communicate 32-bits float values between different platforms (some are computers, some are electronic boards) for data acquisition.
In my communication protocol, I would like to communicate errors using NAN floats. The issue is, there are many NAN and I would like to use one in particular 0x7FA00000.

So, I would like to have a header in which I define:

```
#define DAQ_SYSTEM_ERROR  (0x7FA00000)
```

The issue is, this is a valid 32 bit integer and doing:

```
float value = DAQ_SYSTEM_ERROR;
```

does not yield the desired result.

Is there a way to dot this without too much code? In particulat, is there a way to use reinterpret cast directive to thell the compiler what I want? I feel it should be possible, but I can't manage it.

The code must work in C, C++, Objective-C and Swift.

**EDIT**

Thank you for your comments. I am indeed only interested in one value. The idea is to get the float, then check against NAN (defined as `0x7FA00000`) to know if the value retrieved is a valid measurement (and should be recorded) or if an error occured somewhere, in which case the value should be discarded and a flag raised. On the "sending" platform, somewhere a float value is affected a `0x7FA00000` value. On the recieving platform, the bytes are first decoded, compared to `0x7FA00000`, then stuffed in a float if everything went well.

Comment: `float value = 1./0` MAY(may just as much not, I dont know if standard says whether this is UB or not) give you nan. Edit: Additionally, you can try using union and set the integer to 0x7FA00000 and then pull the float value out, but that is endian-dependant

Comment: @Creris, There are 16,777,214 different ways of representing NAN values for IEEE single-precision floats, and the OP wants a specific one of those.

Comment: `union a{ int a; float b }u; u.a = 0x7FA00000; return u.b;` should do the trick. Again this is endian-dependant

Comment: Swift is quite different from C/C++/Objective-C. I would suggest that you ask about Swift in a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am indeed only interested in one value. The idea is to get the float, then check against NAN (defined as `0x7FA00000`) to know if the value retrieved is a valid measurement (and should be recorded) or if an error occured somewhere, in which case the value should be discarded and a flag raised. On the "sending" platform, somewhere a float value is affected a `0x7FA00000` value. On the recieving platform, the bytes are first decoded, compared to `0x7FA00000`, then stuffed in a float if everything went well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to specify an exact bit pattern to be cast into a float at compile time. ((float)0x7FA00000) will just become 2141192192.0. The only way to get specific bits into a float value is through a pointer at runtime:

```
float fval;
uint32_t fbits = 0x7FA00000;

. . .

memmove(&fval, &fbits, sizeof float);
```

Most compilers would also accept:

```
*((uint32_t *)(& fval)) = fbits;
```

Though the memmove() is more portable.

Comment: Thank you. You gave me an idea : use an union, declare a global const static variable, and fill my #define macro to refer to it. This way I do not need to cnahge much of my code (up until now errors were reported using physically impossible values for floats).